# AngularJS: Filtering results with two parameters taken from inputs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, search, filter

I have this simple Angular app which displays movies in table format and has a search input and dropdown (select element) with genre values to filter/search results. I am trying to figure out how I can filter my results by both terms typed into the search input AND the dropdown.

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/paxatiw/1/edit?html,js,console,output)

Whenever a value is selected from the dropdown, you will see the console log `$scope.selectedValue`. Is there a way I can pass this to the search input (with an `ng-model="searchBar"`)?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Basically, I want to be able to filter my results by Genre if need be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add another filter with the pipe.
Like:

```
ng-repeat="movie in movies | filter:searchBar | filter: selectedGenre | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse"
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!